# is it possible to make cargo install installing dependent cdylib dlls

Tags: windows, installation, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I'm on windows and have

a Rust cdylib

```
[package]
name = "test1dll"
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

and a Rust binary which depends on that dll

```
[package]
name = "test1"
[dependencies]
test1dll = { path = "..." }
```

and am looking for a way to make

```
cargo install
```

install both, the `test1.exe` and `test1dll.dll`, or, if it's not possible with cargo, for a not too complicated alternative.

*The library needs to be a dll so i can `LoadLibrary` it. A static library won't work.*

I can see the binary and the dll in the target/*/deps directory but `cargo install` only installs the executable.

Running `cargo install` from the dll project itself gives a

> error: no packages found with binaries or examples.

which matches with the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-install.html)

> This command manages Cargo's local set of installed binary crates.
> Only packages which have executable [[bin]] or [[example]] targets can
> be installed

but since it's a useful scenario to deploy a binary together with a dll on windows and Rust even offers the possibility to compile cdylib targets into dlls i'm wondering if there's a way doing this with cargo. Unfortunately i'm new to Rust and may be searching using the wrong keywords.

I thought [this](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3028-cargo-binary-dependencies.html) might come close but the runtime is explicitly excluded:

> Note that cargo only supplies these dependencies when building your
> crate. If your program or library requires artifacts at runtime, you
> will still need to handle that yourself by some other means.

And either i use it wrong or [cdylib-plugin](https://github.com/jeff-davis/cdylib-plugin.rs) also doesn't help with installing the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a dll together with a exe with cargo is indeed not possible. But it's possible to add the dll binary stream as a blob to the exe and recreate the dll on first run.
The are two drawbacks:

1. cargo uninstall won't uninstall the dll
2. when using a sub-package to create the dll during build, the package cannot be published [because](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-exclude-and-include-fields)

> Regardless of whether exclude or include is specified, the following
> files are always excluded: Any sub-packages will be skipped (any
> subdirectory that contains a Cargo.toml file).

This could be solved by creating the Cargo.toml of the sub-package during build.rs of the main package. Cargo will complain with a

> error: failed to verify package tarball Caused by: Source directory
> was modified by build.rs during cargo publish. Build scripts should
> not modify anything outside of OUT_DIR.

but also hints at

> To proceed despite this, pass the `--no-verify` flag.

so this is fine.

### The basic process is like this:

1. create a sub-package defining the cdylib
2. create a build.rs in the main package which

- invokes cargo build for the sub-package

:

```
std::process::Command::new("cargo")
    .stdout(std::process::Stdio::inherit())
    .current_dir(sub_package_dir)
    .arg("build")
    .arg("--release")
    .arg("-vv")
    .status()
    .unwrap();
```

- and then creates a rust source on the fly containing the dll byte stream and a function to access it

:

```
let dll_src_str = format!(
    "const DLL_BIN: &[u8] = include_bytes!(r\"{}\");
    pub fn dll_bin() -> &'static [u8] {{ DLL_BIN }}",
    dll_path);
let mut dll_src_file =
    std::fs::File::create(dll_src_path).unwrap();
use std::io::prelude::*;
let write_ok = dll_src_file.write_all(dll_src_str.as_bytes());
```

After the build.rs has finished executing, the build process will find and compile the created additional source.

3. create the dll file during program execution

:

```
pub fn create_dll() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let dll_bytes = dll_contents::dll_bytes();
    let mut dll_file = std::fs::File::create(dll_path).unwrap();
    use std::io::prelude::*;
    return dll_file.write_all(dll_bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rust is meant to compile to a single program, which is one of the arguments that C++ users use against Rust. Rust binaries are much larger because all the libraries are statically linked instead of dynamically linked. Is there a specific reason that you need to dynamically link instead of statically link?

The target/*/deps folder contains the compiled libraries that are statically linked to your binary.

Comment: I don't want to argue for or against Rust, but i need a dll to be able to [inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) it into a process.

Comment: `cargo install` isn't intended to be a full-function package deployment solution. It's meant to streamline the common case for installing developer tools like cargo-watch or ripgrep without accepting responsibility to compete with the features offered by your platform's recommended packaging solution.

Comment: What if it's a developer tool that utilizes LoadLibrary?